# Having trouble getting javascript to calculate fields

Tags: javascript, forms, input, field

I have tried a couple different ways and I feel like this one is the closest to working, however it is not working. I was hoping that someone could point out and explain what I am doing wrong. I think that `parseFloat` could be my issue, but I am not sure.

```
window.onload = function () {
    var purchPrice = document.getElementById('purchPrice');
    var warrMile = document.getElementById('warrMile');
    var currentMile = document.getElementById('currentMile');
    var purchMile = document.getElementById('purchMile');
    var mileAdjPerct = 0;
    var mileAdjEach = 0;
    var mileAdjTotal = 0;   
}

function warrUpdate() {
    var warrPerct = (parseFloat(currentMile.value) - parseFloat(purchMile.value)) / parseFloat(warrMile.value);
    var warrEach = parseFloat(purchPrice.value) * warrPerct;
    var warrTotal = warrEach * 4;

    parseFloat(document.getElementById('mileAdjPerct').value = warrPerct);
    parseFloat(document.getElementById('mileAdjEach').value = warrEach);
    parseFloat(document.getElementById('mileAdjTotal').value = warrTotal);
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hmhxybLL/

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: What is it doing now? What should it be doing?

Comment: Nothing is being displayed into the fields that would show results as the form is filled out. It should be filling in the three lower fields as the top four are filled.

Comment: What are you trying to do with your final 3 lines? It looks like you're getting and setting in the same statement.

Comment: Your first problem is that all your variables are local to the `onload` handler, so you can't access them from `warrUpdate`.

Comment: I am trying to subtract `purchMile` from `currentMile` and divide it by `warrMile` for the first field

Comment: Also remove the parsefloats from around the last statements. No need to parsefloat the result of a value assignment. Also the jsFiddle needs to be changed to "in head' from the "on load" event on the left http://jsfiddle.net/otLdc9dL/1/

Comment: Thank you all for help and mplungjan thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues with your code, the main one is that the variables you want to manipulate are locally scoped in the onload callback function. You have to make the variables global, but that's a bad idea, so among the many things one can do to avoid global variables, one is to encapsulate all your code in a `warranty` object:

```
<fieldset id="milewarr" onSubmit="milewarr()">
    <p>Purchase Price Per Tire: <input type="number" name="purchPrice" id="purchPrice" onChange="warranty.update();" /></p>
    <p>Mileage Warranty: <input type="number" name="warrMile" id="warrMile" onChange="warranty.update();" /></p>
    <p>Current Vehicle Mileage: <input type="number" name="currentMile" id="currentMile" onChange="warranty.update();" /></p>
    <p>Mileage at Purchase: <input type="number" name="purchMile" id="purchMile" onChange="warranty.update();" /></p>
    <br />
    <p>Adjustment Percentage: <input type="number" id="mileAdjPerct" readonly /></p>
    <p>Adjustment Amount Each Tire: <input type="number" id="mileAdjEach" readonly /></p>
    <p>Adjustment Discount Total: <input type="number" id="mileAdjTotal" readonly /></p>
</fieldset>
```

JS:

```
var warranty = (function() {
  var purchPrice, warrMile, currentMile, purchMile, mileAdjPerct, mileAdjEach, mileAdjTotal;

  return {
     init: function() {      
        purchPrice = document.getElementById('purchPrice');
        warrMile = document.getElementById('warrMile');
        currentMile = document.getElementById('currentMile');
        purchMile = document.getElementById('purchMile');
        mileAdjPerct = document.getElementById('mileAdjPerct');
        mileAdjEach = document.getElementById('mileAdjEach');
        mileAdjTotal = document.getElementById('mileAdjTotal');
     },
     update: function() {
        var warrPerct = (currentMile.value - purchMile.value) / warrMile.value; // caution: you should check for a divide by 0 first
        var warrEach = purchPrice.value * warrPerct;
        var warrTotal = warrEach * 4;
        mileAdjPerct.value = warrPerct;
        mileAdjEach.value = warrEach;
        mileAdjTotal.value = warrTotal;
     }
  };
})();

window.onload = warranty.init;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sebnukem/hmhxybLL/10/